# isdigit() not recognising "1" as a numeric value

Tags: c++, validation

I am parsing a string, validating whether a number inside the string is an int.

```
std::string segmentS
if(!isdigit(std::stoi(segmentS))){
    std::cout<<"Not a location +"<<segmentS<<std::endl;

    //does something
    break;
}
```

`segmentS` is the substring that is suppose to be the integer 
Even when I ensure that `segmentS` is a number, `!isdigit(std::stoi(segmentS))` still holds true. Even when segmentS is printed out after the not a location message, it is 1 which is a number, however it isn't being seen as a number, when it runs into this if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::stoi(segmentS)` will convert `segmentS` to an `int` value, which is then passed into `isdigit`, except `isdigit` assumes the input is a **character**.

Remove the call to `stoi`.

Comment: Removing the call to `stoi` will leave you passing a string instead of a character.

Answer (score 1):

isdigit takes a single char as an input, not an integer.